# Look at motion pictures without Google Photos

Tags: photos, google-camera

Google Camera can take "motion pictures", pictures in which a quick video is taken with the photo.

I'd like to be able to look at them from my phone without using Google Photos. How do I do so?

Comment: Related: [How do I view google's motion photos on my windows PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/196831/3573)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the related question! I've edited it to remove the last part about how they're formatted, just so it's clear it's a different question